# In Java, how can I convert a string to a double (not Double)?

Tags: java, string, double

It's part of a school lab and I've researched and I can't find anything to accomplish this task. I'm reading in lines from a file using FileReader and BufferedReader. The data in the file is a name and an age in the following format:

John doe 20

Jane doe 30

etc. I already have code that will take each line and split as such:
split[0] = {"John", "doe", "20"}

I need to get the "20" and store in an array of doubles such as double[0] = 20;

The reason it has to be a double and not Double is because that part of the code in the assignment is already written and I'm sure I cannot just decide to change everything and use a Double instead. How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Double.parseDouble(yourString)

Comment: And you can go from Double to double in a nanosecond, so that's no reason to wonder how to get the other.

Comment: You should read into `autoboxing` and `unboxing` in Java. There should virtually be no issues between Double and double.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).

As you can see the static method returns a primitive `double` and not an object `Double`:

```
public static double parseDouble(String s)
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strNumber = "20";
    double myParsedDouble = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);

    System.out.println(myParsedDouble);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get it into a for loop and start iterating... I'll just use `List` to manipulate the data, since we don't know how many matches there are (and thus, we cannot set up an array).

```
String[] startingArray; // Whatever you put in here
List<Double> endingList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (String element : startingArray) {
    try {
        endingList.add(Double.parseDouble(element));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // do nothing if it doesn't parse
        // note that catching exceptions do not have an adverse effect on performance
    }
}

// Either, if you want it in a Double[]... or
Double[] endingArray = endingList.toArray(new Double[endingList.size()]);

// If you want a double[], start iterating...
double[] endingArray = new double[endingList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < endingList.size(); i++) {
    endingArray[0] = endingList.get(0);
}
```